# Adjust video capture input port using C++ / python

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg

I am having a video capture device (VCD) that acquires frames from a TV which have various output ports (VGA, HDMI, DVI). I read these frames using C++/OpenCV, process them and then show the output on a C++/Qt QLabel.

My problems show up when I change the input port (DVI to HDMI or HDMI to VGA,...), at then I need to manually open the crossbar dialog window for the VCD and switch the input port.

Shows command window with ffmpeg command line + crossbar window for the video capture device

[image]

Moreover, for each input port, I need to adjust some parameters relating to color range, scaling size and wire's length.

I need to automate this process of selecting the right input port with the corresponding right parameters using a C++ or python code.

I was searching for a way to read all the input pins of the crossbar dialog box for the video capture device and this set/unset the required pins.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I was searching for a way to read all the input pins of the crossbar dialog box for the video capture device and this set/unset the required pins. I need a way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example in C++/WinAPI how you can set/unset the `VIDEO INPUT` pins on settings dialog. This code assumes, that checkboxes are children elements of the main dialog; there can be case, when they are nested inside the tab control "Custom settings", so in this case you need find the that tab at first.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>


int main(int, char **)
{
    // Find the dialog
    HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "%Your settings dialog caption%");

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "cannot find settings dialog" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::map<std::string, HWND> options;

    // Get first dialog element
    HWND h = GetWindow(hwnd, GW_CHILD);

    char caption[250];

    std::vector<std::string> inputs{
        "1/HDMI",
        "2/DVI-D",
        "3/COMPONENT",
        "DVI",
        "4/VGA",
        "SOG",
        "5/SDI",
        "6/COMPOSITE",
        "7/S-VIDEO",
        "8/AUTO"
    };

    while (h != NULL)
    {
        // Get element text
        if (GetWindowTextA(h, caption, 250))
        {
            std::string scaption(caption);
            // Check the text, if it's in the list of the option, put it into map.
            if (std::find(inputs.begin(), inputs.end(), scaption) != inputs.end())
            {
                options[caption] = h;
            }
        }
        h = GetWindow(h, GW_HWNDNEXT);
    }

    // Check the 4/VGA option.
    SendMessageA(options["4/VGA"], BM_CLICK, 0, 0); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I need to do, however, I want to modify the code to read from tabs as you have suggested, also to get values from drop menus within the GUI. where can I find good materials to teach me how to write a code like yours?

Comment: Also, is there any other libraries to do the same with python?? Can I also use this same code if I am using Ubuntu?? Is there any alternative in Qt??

Comment: @Tarek this code uses WinAPI functions, so it's not easily portable to other platforms. But it's possible to port to Ubuntu - just use it's API for iterating through the dialog elements, read their text and change state. _Is there any alternative in Qt??_ I don think so, Qt provide tools for building it's own UI, not to interact with other APIs.

Comment: @Tarek @_I want to modify the code to read from tabs_. You have to get all children of main dialog and find and one with name of the tab "CUSTOM PROPERTIES", then get list of all it's children and find the VIDEO INPUT elements in it.  _also to get values from drop menus within the GUI_ The WinAPI function GetMenu/GetSubMenu should be used for this. _where can I find good materials to teach me how to write a code like yours?_ I recommend to use MSDN for this: just open MSDN reference for one of these functions: it explains in details what function do and also offer links to similar functions.